# <> operator buffer size

Tags: perl, buffer, file-handling

I have a file with very long lines that I need to process and I found that the process gets stuck/'really slow' because the buffer is not big enough or due to the fact that handling a very long line might take a while. Here's a code sample:

```
open FH, "<$fname" or die "...";
while (<FH>) {
    my @arr = split //, $_;
    pop @arr;
    pop @arr;
    ... for some "limited small portion of the string length" number of times ...
    pop @arr;
    if ($arr[-1] eq '0') {
        print "done!\n";
        last;
    }
    push @big_arr, join('', @arr);
}
```

The line processing is not "heavy".

I looked for something to solve it and came across [`PerlIO::buffersize`](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/PerlIO-buffersize-0.001/lib/PerlIO/buffersize.pm) but it looks like it wasn't maintained for a while now and I don't want to use a module with version 0.001. How can I modify the `<>` operator buffer size? Or alternatively, is there any way to know the line length before reading it with `<>`?

Comment: How long a line are we talking here? I don't think there's any particular reason why 'buffer' size is particularly problematic though - I've used this construct with a record separator - quite a few 'lines' long - and it works just fine. Are you sure it's the 'while' loop that's slowing you down?

Comment: @Sobrique I'm not sure, but when I ran this code on a file with much shorter lines, it worked it magic and finished running really fast. The lines are very long. Think of it as if you had a large text file all packed into one or two lines (I don't have any control over these files' format).

Comment: But you do have the ability to set `$/` - record separator. Is there anything appropriate you can 'split' the line up on?

Comment: Sadly, no. Thought of that, but have no distinguishable separator.

Comment: Well, you can also set `$/` to a numeric value for a number of bytes to read.

Comment: You can go to a lower level than `readline` (`<>`) and use `read`.  The [`File::Stream`](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/File-Stream-2.30/lib/File/Stream.pm) may help as well.

Comment: @zdim I didn't know `File::Stream`, you solved a future problem of mine. Thanks!

Comment: @yonyon100: Please give us some idea of the length of the "very long lines" and the total size of the file.

Comment: For example, a file of 20MB with one line in it.

Comment: 20MB is not very large. It takes a fraction of a second to read a line that size on my system, so there's almost certainly something else causing your performance issue. You should use a profiler like [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) instead of guessing about the cause.

Comment: Unfortunately, this module is not installed on the system I'm working on and getting the sysadmin to install it will take more time than I can waste, but thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @yonyon100 You don't need root access/admin privileges to install modules.

Comment: Reading 20MB of data will take around 200ms regardless of the buffer size. If your code is taking significantly over a second to run then it is the processing that is taking the time. I think you should show us the contents of the `while` loop that you say is "not heavy". If you have regular expressions in there then it is easy to write something that looks simple but suffers from *catastrophic backtracking* and will take a disproportionately long time for what it does.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I know, but let's just say that in the place I work they would not like that so much. @Borodin it's just `split`s, `join`s and no regex. Something very simple.

Comment: If it's "very simple" then there's no harm in showing it. Simplify it if you must, but it's important - or comment it all out, and spin your loop to see what happens.

Comment: Added a simplified version

Comment: `my @arr = split //, $_;` iterates through your string one character at a time, so yeah, it's gonna take a while with long lines. This is why [you should always explain your actual problem instead of the solution you think will work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234299); you were barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: it doesn't iterate over all of it, there's a limited number of iterations and it's only a small portion of the string length, I'll add that info

Comment: @yonyon100 *"there's a limited number of iterations"* You didn't pass a limit to `split`, so the only limit is the number of characters in `$_`.  In the case of a 20MB line of ASCII, that's more than 20 million characters. *"it's only a small portion of the string length"* `split //, $_` operates on the full length of `$_`. It doesn't matter if the things you do after that only work on part of the string; the call to `split` is what's expensive.

Comment: I think you should post a new question and explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, complete with sample input and output. Show your current solution and explain your performance requirements, e.g. "I want to process a one-line 20MB file in less than 30 seconds."

Comment: I got confused between the `pop` and the `split`. Need to sleep more, I guess... Of course you are correct about what you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that what you need is this:

`$/` - can be set to a numeric value, for a number of bytes to read from a file.

> Setting $/ to a reference to an integer, scalar containing an integer, or scalar that's convertible to an integer will attempt to read records instead of lines, with the maximum record size being the referenced integer number of characters.

Source: [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)

Comment: That won't change Perl's internal buffer size, but that's highly unlikely to be a problem anyway.

Comment: The OP still wants to read in the data as lines, so this will actually make things slightly slower, as you move the line assembling from C to Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Altering Perl's read buffer size is unlikely to make any significant difference to the speed of your program, and the impact you are seeing is much more likely to be a result of the longer read time from the disk drive itself. Take a look at [*Perl Read-Ahead I/O Buffering*](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=580786) on **perlmonks.org**

Furthermore, implementing your own buffering by using `read` or setting the record separator `$/` to a fixed size, is more than likely to slow down your program, as you still have to separate what you have read into lines of data but now have to do it in Perl code instead of letting perl do it for you in C

Note also that the measure of changing `$/` to a fixed record size will still use Perl's standard, probably 8KB, buffer. The only difference is that the amount of data handed back to you will be determined according to a byte count instead of the position of a separator string

Answer (score 3):

> *How can I modify the `<>` operator buffer size?*

`<>` reads into a scalar that can grow to any size, so I think you are referring to the size of the buffer passed to the `read` system call.

Before 5.14, Perl read from file handles in 4 KiB chunks. 5.14 made this configurable, with a default of 8 KiB.

```
$ perl -e'print("x" x 9_999, "\n") for 1..2' >large_lines

$ strace 5.10.1t/bin/perl -e'my $line = <>' large_lines 2>&1 | grep read.*xxx
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 4096) = 4096

$ strace 5.14.2t/bin/perl -e'my $line = <>' large_lines 2>&1 | grep read.*xxx
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 8192) = 8192
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 8192) = 8192
```

It can only be configured when `perl` is built, using the following command

```sh
./Configure -Accflags=-DPERLIOBUF_DEFAULT_BUFSIZ=8192
```

This applies to all buffered reading functions, including `read`, `readline` (for which `<>` is an alias), `readpipe` and `eof`, but not `sysread`.

---

Note that setting `$/` to a reference to a number will cause `readline` (`<>`) to act as `read`, which is still buffered.

```
$ strace perl -e'$/ = \8193; my $block = <>' large_lines 2>&1 | grep read.*xxx
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 8192) = 8192
read(3, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 8192) = 8192
```

If you actually want to perform a single `read` system call, you need to use `sysread`.

```
$ strace perl -e'sysread(STDIN, $buf, 8193)' <large_lines 2>&1 | grep read.*xxx
read(0, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"..., 8193) = 8193
```